# alt tags of the images are not saving/emtpy

Tags: images, conditional-tags, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

When I try to add an alt tag of an image via the library in Wordpress the alt tag is not saving. After leaving and coming back to the library again the alt tag fields are empty.

I’ve tried the following solutions which did not fix this problem:

Remove and upload the images again
Tried several plugins which overwrite the original alt tag
Disabled the WP Smush plugin
Checked the file permissions

I hope someone knows a possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

Theme that I'm using : https://undsgn.com/uncode/

Comment: Have you tried using changing to the TwentySeventeen theme to check if it's an issue with the theme?

Comment: I've tried this and it worked. The problem was in the theme in combination with some plugins. Clean installed it, installed plugins piece by piece and it works now.

Comment: @jobbert, Can you add it as an answer and maybe mark this as answered.

Comment: Didn't want to steal @ChessByte his answer. If he adds it I'll accept it of course!

Comment: Just posted an answer, i didnt notice your last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the theme to wordpress' default theme, twentyseventeen. It could be an issue with the theme